# Advantages of Message Passing

Tags: operating-system, shared-memory

I've been reading about shared memory and message passing and I believe shared memory is faster than message passing, but I can't seem to come across the pros for message passing. Does message passing have any advantages over shared memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest advantage of message passing is that it is easier to build massively parallel hardware. Message passing programming models tend to be more tolerant of higher communication latencies.

Whether shared memory or message passing is faster depends on the problem being solved, the quality of the implementations, and the system(s) it is running on. For example, on a single server, it will probably be easier and higher performance to use a shared memory programming environment. Across a distributed cluster, it will probably be faster to use a message passing library.

Comment: Would it be accurate to say message passing is better for parallel processes and shared memory is better for concurrent processes? Is that basically what you just said or am I on the wrong path.

Comment: The differences between concurrency and parallelism are independent of the tradeoffs between shared memory and message passing.

Due the number of factors involved, it is hard to make simple rules about when message passing or shared memory is better. My examples are cases where the hardware platform will bias you strongly one way or the other, but there are also cases of certain application areas forcing you one way or the other.